# ffmpeg copies packet pts to frame pts during audio decoding without time base conversion

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, decoding, opus

I have [the MKV file](https://github.com/yaskovdev/sandbox/blob/master/ffmpeg-demultiplexing/t.mkv). I am taking an audio stream from it and using ffmpeg and its opus decoder to decode audio packets into audio frames.

The problem is that the resulting frames have unexpected presentation timestamps (pts): during decoding, ffmpeg just copies `pkt->pts` to `frame->pts`, ignoring the fact that the time base for `pkt->pts` is `1/1000`, while for `frame->pts` it is `1/48000` (which means they definitely cannot be the same).

Setting `pkt_timebase` of the audio decoder [to `1/1000`](https://github.com/yaskovdev/sandbox/blob/master/ffmpeg-demultiplexing/main.cpp#L287) does not help.
I also tried using `libopus` audio decoder instead of `opus` (which is considered experimental), but the issue is still there.

How to tell ffmpeg that the time base conversion is needed? Or setting `frame->pts` manually after decoding is the only option?

I have tried the same test with a really old ffmpeg version (3.0). It sets `frame->pts` to `AV_NOPTS_VALUE`, which seems more correct behavior than the current one. Can it be a bug in ffmpeg introduced sometime after version 3.0 and the `frame->pts` should always be `AV_NOPTS_VALUE` if the decoder cannot assign it by itself (both `opus` and `libopus` cannot, according to their `caps_internal`)?

The project to reproduce the issue is [here](https://github.com/yaskovdev/sandbox/blob/master/ffmpeg-demultiplexing/main.cpp). [Here](https://github.com/yaskovdev/sandbox/blob/master/ffmpeg-demultiplexing/main.cpp#L109) it prints `pkt->pts` (before decoding) and `frame->pts` (after decoding) and they happen to be the same.

Comment: I am not well versed in the C++ API of ffmpeg, but you probably have to manually [resample the audio](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.11/group__lavc__resample.html)

Comment: @eike, thank you for the response. The reason I do the decoding is because I have to resample the frames afterwards and re-encode using another codec. The problem is that in order to do the resampling properly, the source frames already should have the proper pts assigned, shouldn't they? But currently, even before resampling, I can see that the frames have pts with interval 20 time units (1/48000 s) and each frame has 960 samples. Which means there's not enough time to play all the samples for any frame. So I have to either reset pts to AV_NOPTS_VALUE, or make ffmpeg assign the pts properly.

Comment: You'll have to manually convert it  See https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/7d377558a6/fftools/ffmpeg.c#L2349

Comment: @Gyan, thank you! Just curious, why doesn't ffmpeg do it during decoding? The necessity to convert manually doesn't seem to be documented nor it is present in the [official decoding example](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.0/decode__video_8c_source.html). To me it seems very unobvious that the manual conversion is needed after decoding.